# Weird Android NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I have an error and I have been pouring over the stack traces for about and hour and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

This is eventually going control a robot and includes many more features but what I'm doing now is trying to make sure the phone is connected to the robot's wifi network. I'm am doing this by testing for a page (192.168.240.1/handshake) and seeing what it returns. Currently it works perfectly when I'm connected to the robot but it crashes if im not conneced to it. I've attempted to comment out a lot of my code but the problem persists.

```
 package com.ruralsurvivor.robotcontrolapp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.net.wifi.WifiInfo;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView t;
    TextView t2;
    Button b;
    String z;
    String lResponse;
    private Handler handler = new Handler();
    public Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            update();
            handler.postDelayed(runnable, 50);
        }
        public void update() {
            int numberOfLevels = 100;
            android.net.wifi.WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
            WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
            int level = WifiManager.calculateSignalLevel(wifiInfo.getRssi(), numberOfLevels);
            ProgressBar firstBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.determinateBar);
            firstBar.setProgress(level);
            wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
            WifiInfo info = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
            String ssid = info.getSSID();
            t.setText("Network: " + ssid);
            z = "http://192.168.240.1/handshake";
            try {
                lResponse = new HTTPRequest().execute(z).get();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

                lResponse = "error";
            }
            if (!lResponse.equals("Schmuck me sideways")) {
                b.setEnabled(false);
                b.setAlpha(0.75f);
                t2.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#c10508"));
                t2.setText("Not Connected");
            } else {
                b.setEnabled(true);
                b.setAlpha(1f);
                t2.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#1eb500"));
                t2.setText("Connected");
            }

        }
    };
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        t = new TextView(this);
        t=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        t2 = new TextView(this);
        t2 =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        start();
    }

    public void start() {
        runnable.run();
    }
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void clickMe(View v) {
        handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
        setContentView(R.layout.control);
        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        myWebView.loadUrl("http://192.168.240.1:8080/?action=stream");
    }
}
```

This is my stack trace:

```
07-06 23:21:15.713 18517-18517/com.ruralsurvivor.robotcontrolapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                   Process: com.ruralsurvivor.robotcontrolapp, PID: 18517
                                                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ruralsurvivor.robotcontrolapp/com.ruralsurvivor.robotcontrolapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2198)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5097)
                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
                                                                                       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                                       at com.ruralsurvivor.robotcontrolapp.MainActivity$1.update(MainActivity.java:57)
                                                                                       at com.ruralsurvivor.robotcontrolapp.MainActivity$1.run(MainActivity.java:34)
                                                                                       at com.ruralsurvivor.robotcontrolapp.MainActivity.start(MainActivity.java:83)
                                                                                       at com.ruralsurvivor.robotcontrolapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:79)
                                                                                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5248)
                                                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1110)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2162)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257) 
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139) 
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210) 
                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5097) 
                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 
                                                                                       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

this is the code I'm using to test the wifi:

```
package com.ruralsurvivor.robotcontrolapp;

import android.os.AsyncTask;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class HTTPRequest extends AsyncTask< String, String, String >
{

    protected String theHTTPString = null;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground( String... uri )
    {
        URL url = null;
        try
        {
            url = new URL( uri[0] );
        }
        catch( MalformedURLException e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String responseString = null;
        try
        {
            HttpURLConnection httpclient = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            int lResponseCode = httpclient.getResponseCode();
            if( lResponseCode != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK )
            {
                httpclient.disconnect();
                throw new IOException( "RESPONSE REJECTED WITH ERROR CODE: " + lResponseCode );
            }
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader( httpclient.getInputStream() ));
            StringBuffer lStringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
            String inputLine;
            while( (inputLine = in.readLine()) != null )
            {
                lStringBuffer.append( inputLine );
            }
            httpclient.disconnect();
            in.close();
            responseString = lStringBuffer.toString();
        }
        catch( IOException e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return responseString;
        }

        theHTTPString = responseString;

        return responseString;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your error at com.ruralsurvivor.robotcontrolapp.MainActivity$1.update(MainActivity.java:57)  Maybe your Button b; is the error

Comment: Ranjith Kumar the weird thing is that when I comment that line or any of the others it still gives me an error on the same line.

Comment: pls post your xml file also

Comment: which is line 57?

Comment: @ScaryWombat if (!lResponse.equals("Schmuck me sideways")) {

Comment: Yes, there are a few places in your asynctask that you return `null`

Comment: @ScaryWombat suggestions for a fix?

Comment: Change `String responseString = null;` to `String responseString = "error";`  **But** also I think that there is some more information lower down in your stacktrace that is showing the root cause

Comment: @ScaryWombat I tried something like that earlier but I'm not sure Android studio updated the apk before launching it

Comment: so? shall I send someone over ;-)

Comment: @ScaryWombat ha! That's funny. Would the stack trace show an error from the httprequest class if that's where the error was. I moved lines up and down in my code and it still told me error was on the same line

Comment: Can you post your entire stacktrace?

Comment: @ScaryWombat there are various other error but no other fatal errors. I'll post it all tomorrow as I'm not near my computer